# Вложенная сетка в Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, адаптивная-верстка, bootstrap4

По заданию нужно, используя сетку Bootstrap 4  сверстать секцию, состоящую из левого блока с классом *"col-xl-3 col-lg-4"*, содержащим только заголовок секции, и правого с классом *"col-xl-9 col-lg8 col-md-12"*, содержащего шесть карточек, шириной в три колонки на разрешении xl. Какие классы bootstrap-grid.css нужно применить к элементам правого блока?

```html
<section class="section section-broadcasts">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-12">
            <h2 class="section__title section-broadcasts__title">
              Broadcasts
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg8 col-md-12">
            <div class="wrapper flex">
              <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <div class="broadcast flex">
                  <h3>
                    Broadcast 1
                  </h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <div class="broadcast flex">
                  <h3>
                    Broadcast 2
                  </h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <div class="broadcast flex">
                  <h3>
                    Broadcast 3
                  </h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <div class="broadcast flex">
                  <h3>
                    Broadcast 4
                  </h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <div class="broadcast flex">
                  <h3>
                    Broadcast 5
                  </h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <div class="broadcast flex">
                  <h3>
                    Broadcast 6
                  </h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div><!--/wrapper-->
          </div>
        </div><!--/row-->
      </div><!--/container-->

    </section>
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: почему внутренность правого не заворачиваете в свои классы, а не в `.row` ? зы: емнип там был готовый `.d-flex` вместо вашего `flex`

Comment: Насколько я помню .row адекватно работает только внутри контейнера, а мне нужен блок, занимающий 9 колонок.

Comment: @Андрей [Nested rows](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#nesting)

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло!